# How can I iterate over and modify the values in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
records = {'foo':foo, 'bar':bar, 'baz':baz}
```

I want to change the values to `0` if it is `None`. How can I do this?

eg:

```
records = {'foo':None, 'bar':None, 'baz':1}
```

I want to change `foo` and `bar` to `0`.
Final dict:

```
records = {'foo':0, 'bar':0, 'baz':1}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another way

```
records.update((k, 0) for k,v in records.iteritems() if v is None)
```

Example

```
>>> records
{'bar': None, 'baz': 1, 'foo': None}
>>> records.update((k, 0) for k,v in records.iteritems() if v is None)
>>> records
{'bar': 0, 'baz': 1, 'foo': 0}
```

Comment: `records.items()` for Python 3 for anyone who came here and wondered why copy-paste didn't work.

Answer (score 20):

```
for k in records:
    if records[k] is None:
        records[k] = 0
```

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
for key, value in records.iteritems():
    if value is None:
        records[key] = 0
```

Answer (score 9):

```
for k, v in records.items():
    if v is None:
        records[k] = 0
```

Comment: There is a typo in the last line (`"k"` instead of `k`).  Furthermore, `iteritems()` is preferred over `items()` in this situation (but it does not matter much most of the time).

Comment: If you downvote, it is good etiquette to leave a reason for doing so.

Comment: @Alex: I removed my down vote. The answer is no longer wrong, as it was when I voted. (You didn't use .items() then)

Comment: @Thomas: I often edit my answers quickly after posting them. I dislike your implication that I copied from Sven's answer. Please consider being less pushy in the future. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex: I didn't mean to imply that you copied Sven's answer and certainly didn't mean to be pushy. I just pointed out that it was similar to Sven's answer, which also was posted first. I did also remove that comment when it was no longer constructive.

Comment: Between two options, I will always choose the most readable one unless there is any real advantage on the obfuscated version. So upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intimidate or annoy other code maintainers, there's an ugly one-liner that will do the trick:

```
records.update(map(lambda (k,v):(k,{v:v,None:0}[v]), records.items()))
```

Example use:

```
>>> records = {"hey":None, "you":0}
>>> records.update(map(lambda (k,v):(k,{v:v,None:0}[v]), records.items()))
>>> records
{'you': 0, 'hey': 0}
```

Comment: +1 for using a lambda, and for intimidating code maintainers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
records = dict( ( k,0 if v is None else v ) for k, v in records.items() )

def zero_if_none( x ):
    return 0 if x is None else x
records = dict( ( k, zero_if_none( records[k] ) ) for k in records )
```

Comment: There's a typo in `return 0 if z ...`; `z` should be `x` :)